# Why is there SOQL when apparently the DB used by Salesforce is Oracle DB?

Tags: soql, community

This article suggests that the DB used by Salesforce is Oracle -- [https://www.xplenty.com/blog/the-salesforce-database-explained/#:~:text=Get%20Started-,About%20the%20Salesforce%20Database,have%20a%20semi%2Dsymbiotic%20relationship](https://www.xplenty.com/blog/the-salesforce-database-explained/#:%7E:text=Get%20Started-,About%20the%20Salesforce%20Database,have%20a%20semi%2Dsymbiotic%20relationship).

If that is so, then why is Salesforce abstracting PL/SQL and instead offers SOQL?

Comment: See [SOQL for the SQL Developer](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/03/soql-sql-developer.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce is a multi-tenant platform. Multiple orgs are hosted on the same underlying hardware and software instances.

Because of the multitenant nature of the platform, resources are exposed within orgs through abstractions that both implement multitenancy (exposing the content of each isolated customer environment) and support the requirements of multitenancy (data protection, managing performance impacts on shared resources).

[Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_concepts_multitenancy_and_metadata.htm) contains information about how the schema and structure of each org are implemented on underlying shared databases:

> Multitenancy requires that applications behave reliably, even when architects are making Salesforce-supported customizations, which include creating custom data objects, changing the interface, and defining business rules. To ensure that tenant-specific customizations do not breach the security of other tenants or affect their performance, Salesforce uses a runtime engine that generates application components from those customizations. By maintaining boundaries between the architecture of the underlying application and that of each tenant, Salesforce protects the integrity of each tenant’s data and operations.

> When organizations create custom objects, the platform tracks metadata about the objects and their fields, relationships, and other object definition characteristics. **Salesforce stores the application data for all virtual tables in a few large database tables, which are partitioned by tenant and serve as heap storage. The platform’s engine then materializes virtual table data at runtime by considering the corresponding metadata.**

Emphasis mine. This distinction is one key reason (but not the only reason) why query operations are presented within an org through the abstraction layer that is SOQL.

Comment: tl;dr; customers don't get direct access to the underlying database because they share this database with others, and this access needs to be controlled and metered so everyone has access to their stuff and only their stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If that article is fact-based, it also states:

> Salesforce also utilized PostgreSQL and a few other languages, but the
> majority of its platform runs on Oracle Databases.

SQL implementations for both databases are powerful comprising of cube, rollup, analytics, etc. Oracle has a relatively complex SQL Syntax compared to PostgreSQL. Oracle follows ‘Oraclism’ when developing Syntax while PostgreSQL tends to follow the standard way. Both have non-standard built-in procedural extensions (Oracle PL/SQL and PostgreSQL pg/SQL).

Therefore, putting an abstraction layer is to encapsulate its implementations, and the choice of database technologies.